# How to define a two-dimensional list in Python like this?

Tags: python

In my understanding, two-dimensional list in Python is just a list of lists, so a two-dimensional list can be defined as follows:

```
a=[[0,0],[1,1]]
```

To get an element of this two-dimensional list, we have to write

```
a[0][1]
```

while the following form

```
a[0,1]
```

will cause an error. That is, indexes should be separated by `[]`, instead of being putting together in one `[]` separated by comma.

However, in page 59 of the book "Python Essential Reference", Fourth Edition, David M. Beazley, I read:

[image]

In the image above, we can see that multidimensional list can be written in the form of, say, `m[1:10, 3:20]`. But how to define such a two-demensional list in Python so that we can get an element using `m[1,2]` form? Thanks.

Comment: `a[0,1]` is equivalent to `a[(0, 1)]`, which calls `a.__getitem__((0, 1))`. `a[0][1]` first gets the first item in `a` (also with `a.__getitem__`), then gets that returned list's second item. You'd have to implement `__getitem__` on your own class to handle these cases, which is why the document doesn't include builtin lists in its "multidimensional data structures".

Comment: @Blender So the slices shown in the book is for user-defined classes?

Comment: @Blender I have the same question as aIKid

Comment: @user2384994: Builtin lists only support indices and "regular" slices, not tuples of slices. `__getitem__` is just a regular method, so it's up to you to implement it. You could even do something like `obj[{'foo': 12}]`.

Comment: @Blender I see. Thank you for the mind-opening comment. Do you mind writing your comments as an answer so that I can tick it?

Comment: Have you looked into the [NumPy package](http://www.numpy.org/)?  It has many-dimensional arrays and much more builtin.

Comment: @John1024 No, I didn't. Could you please give an example of such builtin array? btw, are you sure many-dimensional arrays in NumPy are builtin instead of user-defined to allow for a[0,1] form of indexing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That is, indexes should be separated by `[]`, instead of being putting together in one `[]` separated by comma.

`a[0,1]` is equivalent to `a[(0, 1)]`, which calls `a.__getitem__((0, 1))`.

`a[0][1]` is equivalent to `a.__getitem__(0).__getitem__(1)`. As you can see, the brackets are really just a nice way of calling `__getitem__`.

Python lists only support integers and `slice` objects as the arguments to `__getitem__`, so you can't write `a[0, 1]`. You can, however, write your own class and have `__getitem__` do whatever you want:

```
>>> class Something(object):
...     def __getitem__(self, arg):
...         return arg
...     
>>> Something()[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, 'foo', ..., 12, 4:2]
    ({1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, 'foo', Ellipsis, 12, slice(4, 2, None))
```

Answer (score 3):

Even though Python lists do not have more than one dimension the notation with two or more indices / slices is needed for arrays / matrices which come with `numpy`. Even though it (intentionally) doesn't belong to the core library it has become a de facto standard for n-dimensional arrays.

Here you can type

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ar = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> ar[0,0]
1
>>> ar[:,0]
array([1, 3])

>>> random_array = np.random.random((100,100))
>>> random_array[50:60,30:35]
array([[ 0.8352567 ,  0.14901839,  0.2409099 ,  0.88278442,  0.84300552],
       [ 0.88403713,  0.54964811,  0.83500869,  0.88258427,  0.90273584],
       [ 0.00271817,  0.94116153,  0.6282039 ,  0.3243262 ,  0.71785796],
       [ 0.0661821 ,  0.99243509,  0.5888741 ,  0.04161134,  0.89517395],
       [ 0.87419943,  0.14761041,  0.06123542,  0.8139316 ,  0.66220133],
       [ 0.24710625,  0.02305463,  0.7301232 ,  0.11279152,  0.57674316],
       [ 0.9893136 ,  0.9711931 ,  0.12936097,  0.49021876,  0.24834283],
       [ 0.48277394,  0.76470469,  0.29348414,  0.43578663,  0.69670601],
       [ 0.43401812,  0.14714134,  0.52015761,  0.40088974,  0.25203087],
       [ 0.9431969 ,  0.04824567,  0.98400652,  0.1129802 ,  0.25518842]])
```

Custom classes seem to be a very special use case - numpy arrays are really used a lot, almost no scientific Python library does not use numpy.

Answer (score 2):

A class like this handles it:

```
class List(list):
  def __getitem__(self, index):
    if type(index) is int:
      return super(List, self).__getitem__(index)
    l = self
    for i in index:
      if not isinstance(l, list)
        raise IndexError('Too many indexes: out of depth.')
      l = l[i]
    return l
```

You can use it like this:

```
>>> l = List([[1,2,3],[3,2,1]])
>>> print l[1,2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the sample codes of user-defined class that support l[1,2] form of indexing.